# What set of commands to use for running Spring Boot Application in Visual Studio Code from terminal?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I am new to Spring Boot. In Visual Studio Code, I have to create a standalone jar executable which will print the list of people in sorted order by name, age and experience.

application.properties: (this was already written in the question)
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>springBoot</groupId>
    <artifactId>frescoCourses</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
             <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
             <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
             <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

My code:
EmployeeService Class

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;

@Service
public class EmployeeService {
     public List<Employee> getEmployees() {
        List<Employee> emp = new ArrayList<>();
        Employee emp1 = new Employee("Sandhya",20,0);
        Employee emp2 = new Employee("Kemp",24,2);
        Employee emp3 = new Employee("Anil",22,3);
        Employee emp4 = new Employee("Kumar",30,6);
        Employee emp5 = new Employee("Tim",32,7);
        emp.add(emp1);
        emp.add(emp2);
        emp.add(emp3);
        emp.add(emp4);
        emp.add(emp5);

        return emp;
    }
}
```

EmployeeController Class

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
public class EmployeeController {

  @Autowired
  EmployeeService employeeService;

  @RequestMapping("/")
    public List<Employee> getEmpList(){
    List<Employee> empController = employeeService.getEmployees();
    Collections.sort(empController);
        return empController;
    }

}
```

DemoApplication

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
```

Employee Class

```
public class Employee implements Comparable<Employee> {

private String name;
private int age;
private int exp;

public Employee(String name, int age, int exp) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.exp = exp;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Employee emp) {
//the comparator logic which I am able to write}}
```

On clicking Run it shows "Build Failure". Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins. maven-resources-plugin3.1.0:(resources)(default resources) on Test/....../application.properties [Permission denied]

Kindly help.

[error image of terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8a2a.png)

Comment: Images are not an appropriate way to show us your error. The image itself is also far too small to be readable. Please paste the error into your question as text.

Comment: The error is: "Build Failure". Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins. maven-resources-plugin3.1.0:(resources)(default resources) on Test/....../application.properties [Permission denied]